# WP update_user_meta() is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

My goal is to create a plugin for counting the number of times a user logs in. But for now, it seems the update_user_meta() is not working or I'm not using it properly. I'm just trying to update a custom variable with the user_id value, so that I can know that I am storing a value in the user_meta.

```
<?php
function user_login_count2($redirect_to, $request, $user) {
    global $user;
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;

    if (isset($user_id)) {
      if ( get_user_meta($user_id, 'login_count2', true) ){
        //$login_count2 = get_user_meta($user_id, 'login_count2', true);
        //$login_count2++;
        //update_user_meta($user_id, 'login_count2', $login_count2); 
        $user_id_test = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_id_test', true);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_id_test', $user_id);

      }else{
          add_user_meta($user_id, 'login_count2', '1');
      }                  
    }else{
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'user_login_count2', 10, 3);

function show_login_counts() {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;

    $user_id_test = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_id_test', true);
    if(isset($_GET['ict']) && $_GET['ict'] == 1){
        echo $user_id;
        echo $user_id_test;
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'show_login_counts');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to follow your code with all the commented out code, and I'm not sure what the purpose of the calls to the various user functions are variables are.

Here's how I would do it:

```
    add_action('wp_login', 'record_user_login', 10, 2);

    function record_user_login($user_login, $user){

        // Get current user ID from the user object
        $user_id = $user->ID;

        // Get previous login count
        $login_count = get_user_meta($user_id, 'login_count', true);

        // Increment login count if it exists, or set it to 1
        if (int_var($login_count)){
            $new_count = $login_count++;
        }
        else {
            $new_count = 1;
        }

        // Update login count in user meta
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'login_count', $new_count);

    }
```

Comment: I tried this, and when I tried to login, it just go to a blank page with url <sitename>/wp-login.php

Comment: That means there's an error in your code.  Check the log.

Comment: I posted the code I used. Could you kindly check it? Thanks!

Comment: If you're getting a white screen, there's an error. Check the log to see what it is.  Also, you can just check the user login count directly in the database.  That's easier than sticking it in the footer.